# xcode gives error about linked swift framework but project builds and run

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've a swift framework that exports the following class

```
@objc public protocol MyClassProt{
    ....
}

@available(iOSMac 10.10, *)
@objc public class MyClass: NSObject, MyClassProt {
    ....
}
```

When I build a test app using this framework on the same workspace everything is ok.

However, when I link this framework to a standalone app with just the compiled framework, xcode complains it can't access the class:

```
import Cocoa
import MyFramework // no problem

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var m: MyClass?  // error: 'MyClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift decleration for this class
                     // 1. 'MyClass' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (MyFramework.MyClass)
```

Also auto complete for the framework api functions doesn't work.

But this code will build and run as expected using all framework apis.

(Note: not sure if related but I added the @objc protocol because when importing to objc project I could see the class and ctor but non of the other apis)

I must be doing something wrong with the framework definition, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Protocol is internal. Make it public as well `@objc public protocol MyClassProt`

Comment: @Kamran I've added `public` to the protocol - no change

Comment: I believe it should've worked as per the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html). I'm not sure what could go wrong.

Comment: Did you mark that class scope as public in settings?

Comment: @Reed I'm relatively new to xcode, can you tell me which setting you're referring to?